# Code after stored procedure query not being executed in nodejs msnodesqlv8

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure and when I run the code below, the code in the function for the query is not being run at all. There is also no error. I am thinking somehow SQL Server is interpreting the query for the stored procedure incorrectly and stalling because if I use a regular query e.g. `select top 1 * from Custom.ExampleTable` it works fine.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8"); 

// example db connection...
const connectionString = "server=dev\\instance1;database=123456;user=ORG\\NAME;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

sql.connect(connectionString, err => {
    console.log("connected: " + connectionString)
    try {
        new sql.Request().input('var', sql.VarChar, 2222).execute('dbo.check_ex', (err, results) => {
            // code not being run...
            console.dir("test")
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } 
            console.log(rows);
        })       
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

})

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Output below:

```
Server is running..
connected: server=dev\\instance1;database=123456;user=ORG\\NAME;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```